# Kindle App not available on my Samsung tablet; how can I access my library?

Tags: kindle

I want to read my many kindle titles on my newish Samsung Tablet but the Kindle app is not available for the model. What can I do?

Comment: Some reviews state the Amazon Kindle app runs on Samsung tablet... and some don't. https://www.amazon.com/Amazon-com-Amazon-for-Tablets/dp/B00AQL8VU4/ref=sr_1_3

Comment: Have you tried the Google Playstore app for Kindle on your android tablet ? For more go to https://www.howtogeek.com/232726/how-to-install-the-google-play-store-on-your-amazon-fire-tablet/

Answer (score 0):

If the latest Kindle version is not available for your device, you could sideload an older one that your tablet would support since you have an Android

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to use the cloud reader. As long as you have a browser, you can read your books from any device.

https://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=1000579091

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use Kindle For Web using Chrome in the new Samsung device

Answer (score 0):

In my old tablet, I had to install the [Amazon App Store](https://www.amazon.com.br/gp/mas/get/android) and there I could find a special version of the app called Kindle for Samsung.